# Null/Empty vs Zero/0 in the defined line

Tags: javascript, html, csv, d3.js

I have a graph which displays several stacked areas and lines. I want to stacked areas to stop at a point and the lines to continue from there.

I achieve this by leaving empty values in the CSV I'm using, and adding this line to each line/area variable:

```
.defined(function(d) {return d.prioFinishA;})
```

This works for a while, however there's a huge problem. This also filters the 0 values. So if I have a Zero somewhere in the CSV, it'll consider it as a missing value, and break the line/area at that point. Considering I want all my lines to finish at 0 value, this is a huge problem.

I found a small workaround, which is using the: 0.00001 value instead of 0, which is pretty close, however this is a pretty ugly "solution".

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: try d.prioFinishA !== ""

Comment: I'm sorry, where do you mean it exactly at? Instead of the .defined lines?

Comment: @CAJ69I No, instead of `return d.prioFinishA` do `return d.prioFinishA !== ""`. In JavaScript these are falsy: `0`, `null`, `undefined`, `""`, `false` and `NaN`. That's why it's filtering the zeros as well.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work either for some reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is not the line generator, but the row function. Let's see it:

You are using a row function (I can see it in your deleted answer) to convert the strings to numbers, like this:

```
function type(d) {
  d.foo = +d.foo
  return d;
}
```

The problem is that, when you do this to empty values, the unary plus convert them to zero:

```js
console.log(+"")
```

And, because of that, you cannot use the correct function inside the `defined`, as explained in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48517447/null-empty-vs-zero-0-in-the-defined-line/48520101?noredirect=1#comment84029936_48517447), which is:

```
.defined(function(d) {return d.prioFinishA !== "";})
```

Look at this demo, I'm using the `defined` correctly, however the empty strings were changed to zero by the row function:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");
var csv = `col,value
1,40
2,30
3,100
4,60
5,
6,
7,90
8,120
9,100`;

var data = d3.csvParse(csv, function(d) {
  d.col = +d.col;
  d.value = +d.value;
  return d;
});

var scale = d3.scaleLinear().range([150, 0]).domain([0, 150])

var lineGen = d3.line()
  .x(d => d.col * 30)
  .y(d => scale(d.value))
  .defined(function(d) {
    return d.value !== ""
  })

var line = svg.append("path")
  .attr("fill", "none")
  .attr("stroke", "teal")
  .attr("stroke-width", 2)
  .attr("d", lineGen(data));
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

So, we have to check in the row function if a value is an empty string and, if not, coerce to number. You can do it with an `if` (preferable, since more readable) or with:

```
d.foo = d.foo && +d.foo;
```

Here is the same demo with that change, now the empty strings don't show up:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");
var csv = `col,value
1,40
2,30
3,100
4,60
5,
6,
7,90
8,120
9,100`;

var data = d3.csvParse(csv, function(d) {
  d.col = +d.col;
  d.value = d.value && +d.value;
  return d;
});

var scale = d3.scaleLinear().range([150, 0]).domain([0, 150])

var lineGen = d3.line()
  .x(d => d.col * 30)
  .y(d => scale(d.value))
  .defined(function(d) {
    return d.value !== ""
  })

var line = svg.append("path")
  .attr("fill", "none")
  .attr("stroke", "teal")
  .attr("stroke-width", 2)
  .attr("d", lineGen(data));
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```